# Проблема с Button и Toast

Tags: java, android, button, ldap, toast

Пишу android приложение на java с ldap авторизацией. Имеется две кнопки, 1 переносит назад на страницу, через вторую должна происходить сама авторизация. При ошибке в EditText должен вылазить Toast с сообщением, но только по нажатию на 2 кнопку, но она вылазит и при нажатии на 1, как  можно решить?

````
    String address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    int port = 389;
    String bindDN = "cn = User, cn = Admin, dc = rifar,  dc = loc";
    String password = "password";
    boolean login_flag = true;

    LDAPConnection c;
    AddRequest addRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_ad);

        ImageButton buttonBackSet2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonBackSet2);
        buttonBackSet2.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button Vvod = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Vvod);
        Vvod.setOnClickListener(this);



    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.buttonBackSet2:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.a1111.MainActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        try
        {
            c = new LDAPConnection(address, port, bindDN, password);
            c.setConnectionName("Connection");
            String con_name = c.getConnectionName();
            long time = c.getConnectTime();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(time));
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connected to LDAP server..."+con_name + " at time" +dateString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (LDAPException e)
        {
            login_flag = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No connection..." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            if(login_flag)
            {
                c.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Closed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
} ```
````

Comment: Лучше на каждую кнопку повесить отдельный слушатель, а не пихать всю логику в один.

Comment: @woesss, не подскажите как сделать? А то не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше на каждую кнопку повесить отдельный слушатель, а не пихать всю логику в один.
Назначать слушатели можно несколькими способами, например используя ссылки на методы:

```java
    String address = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    int port = 389;
    String bindDN = "cn = User, cn = Admin, dc = rifar,  dc = loc";
    String password = "password";
    boolean login_flag = true;

    LDAPConnection c;
    AddRequest addRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_ad);

        ImageButton buttonBackSet2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonBackSet2);
        buttonBackSet2.setOnClickListener(this::onClickBackSet2);

        Button Vvod = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Vvod);
        Vvod.setOnClickListener(this::onClickVvod);
    }

    private void onClickBackSet2(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.a1111.MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void onClickVvod(View view)
    {
        try
        {
            c = new LDAPConnection(address, port, bindDN, password);
            c.setConnectionName("Connection");
            String con_name = c.getConnectionName();
            long time = c.getConnectTime();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
            String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(time));
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Connected to LDAP server..."+con_name + " at time" +dateString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (LDAPException e)
        {
            login_flag = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No connection..." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally
        {
            if(login_flag)
            {
                c.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Closed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Теперь после нажатия на кнопку входа, отсылающую на страницу с этими двумя кнопками, приложение падает:(

Comment: Ну а в логах что?